# How do I remove the string values?

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to figure out on how can I remove the string values. And also when I can remove them all? So here's the code.

HTML:

```
<div id="a"> </div>
<div id="x" onclick="EraseAll()"> </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function ABC(){
    document.getElementById('a').innerHTML += "<img src=\"buttonx.png\" id=\"Erase\" onclick=\"Erase()\"> </div>" + document.getElementById('n').value + document.getElementById('q').value + parseInt(document.getElementById('t').value);
}
```

Ive tried this code, but it won't work,

```
function Erase(){
var n = document.getElementById('n').value;
var q = document.getElementById('q').value;
var t = document.getElementById('t').value;

n = n.replace(n, " ");}
```

I'm still learning Javascript , so if any help would do, and also please only use Javascript, I've been asked to use Javascript only.

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Where is function ABC called?

Comment: Please edit your code to be indented and explain what you are trying to do better so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're looking for this should do it -

```
document.getElementById('n').value = '';
document.getElementById('q').value = '';
document.getElementById('t').value = '';
```